# How can I make my Kivy Label update dynamically when a value is changed?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am working on making a kivy app and have run into a problem where I can't update a label. I'm not sure where to go from here, but I want the date value to be displayed by a label in Class ThirdMenu. Here is all of my code, it is a bit disorganized. I am new to kivy and have not completely grasped all of the concepts so there are most likely many mistakes.

This is the class with the label I want to change:

```
class ThirdMenu(Screen, FloatLayout, EventDispatcher):
theme_cls = ThemeManager()
pickers = None
previous_date = ''
a = NumericProperty(0)

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ThirdMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    global Date


    #Labels
    app = App.get_running_app()
    app.D = Label(text=str(app.a),bold = True,text_size=(None,None),font_size="30sp",pos_hint={'center_x': 0.50, 'y': .8},size_hint_y=None,size = self.size,color=(1, 0, 0, 1))
    self.add_widget(app.D)

    #Buttons

    FBBtn = Button(text ='Back to menu', size_hint =(1, .15), pos_hint ={'x': 0, 'y': 0.85}) 
    self.add_widget(FBBtn) 
    FBBtn.bind(on_press = self.change_screen_menu)



    Builder.load_string(KV)
    self.pickers = Factory.Pickers()

    self.add_widget(self.pickers)
#Screen manager / changing screens route

def change_screen_menu(self, *args):
    self.manager.transition = SlideTransition(direction ='down')
    self.manager.current = 'menu'

    print('Screen is: ' + str(self.manager.current))
def on_a(self, instance, value):
    app = App.get_running_app()
    app.D.text = str(a)
    print (a)
```

The KV string that loads in this class:

```
KV = """ 
<Pickers@Screen>
    name: 'pickers'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(20)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Open date picker"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            opposite_colors: True
            on_release: app.show_example_date_picker()

        MDLabel:
            id: date_picker_label
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            halign: 'center'

        Label:
            id: Date
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            halign: 'center'

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: self.minimum_size
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}

            Label:
                theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                text: "Start on previous date"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: self.texture_size[0]
                color: 0, 0, 0, 0

            MDCheckbox:
                id: date_picker_use_previous_date"""
```

and then my main class with the function to change the date value:

```
class MyApp(App):

theme_cls = ThemeManager()
pickers = None
previous_date = ''
a = StringProperty(0)
def build(self):


    Window.size = (750,1334)
    Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    #set up of screen manager
    sm = ScreenManager()

    #Adding the different screens

    sm.add_widget(MainMenu(name='menu'))
    sm.add_widget(MainApp(name='main'))
    sm.add_widget(SecondMenu(name='second'))
    sm.add_widget(ThirdMenu(name='third'))
    sm.add_widget(FourthMenu(name='fourth'))
    sm.add_widget(TinaMenu(name='tinamenu'))
    sm.add_widget(JohnMenu(name='johnmenu'))

   #Activating the screen manager



    return sm
def show_example_date_picker(self, *args):

    self.pickers = Factory.Pickers()
    if self.pickers.ids.date_picker_use_previous_date.active:
        pd = self.previous_date
        try:
            MDDatePicker(self.set_previous_date, pd.year, pd.month, pd.day).open()
        except AttributeError:
            MDDatePicker(self.set_previous_date).open()
    else:
        MDDatePicker(self.set_previous_date).open()


def set_previous_date(self, date_obj):
    global a
    app = App.get_running_app()
    self.previous_date = date_obj
    self.pickers.ids.date_picker_label.text = str(date_obj)
    app.a = self.pickers.ids.date_picker_label.text
    print(app.a)
    ThirdMenu.text = str(app.a)
```

Thank you for reading, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you give a more minimal example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several strange things going on in your code:

1. `ThirdMenu` class does not need to extend all those classes. Just extending `Screen` is enough since `Screen` is already a `RelativeLayout` and an `EventDispatcher`.
2. Your `Pickers` class extends `Screen`, but you are not using it as a `Screen`. You can just extend `RelativeLayout` instead
3. You are using `self.pickers = Factory.Pickers()` in two different places. That gives you two different, unrelated instances of the `Pickers` class. Making changes to the `Pickers` instance that you create in the `MyApp` class will have no effect on the `Pickers` instance that is displayed in `ThirdMenu`. You can use something similar to point #5, below, to access the correct instance of `Pickers` in the `show_example_date_picker()` metod.
4. In your `set_previous_date()` method you use `app = App.get_running_app()`, but in that method `self` is the app.
5. And finally, in your `set_previous_date()` method, you can set the label text with

   self.root.get_screen('third').pickers.ids.Date.text = str(date_obj)

This accesses the `root` of the `App`, which is the `ScreenManager`, then gets the `Screen` with the name `third` (`ThirdScreen`), then accesses the `pickers` attribute of `ThirdScreen`, then accesses the `ids` dictionary of `Pickers`, from which it accesses the `Date` (the `Label` within `Pickers`), and sets the `text` attribute of that `Label` to the picked date.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the label id, you can change its value on the main file.

(...)

```
Label:
            id: Date
            theme_text_color: 'Primary'
            halign: 'center'
```

(...)

On main.py
(...)

```
def change_date(newValue):    
            self.Date = newValue
```

(...)